# Google Map FragmentActivity in Nav Drawer

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

So I am trying to implement google maps inside one of my fragments within my Navigation Drawer. However, the fragment extends FragmentActivity whereas the Navigation Drawer is expecting just a regular fragment. Before I added the code for the map, including the extends FragmentActivity, everything was fine. However, now that I added it, it doesn't like it. I am trying to follow the code given here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start

It isn't liking this part:

```
else if (id == R.id.nav_third_layout) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new ThirdFragment()).commit();
            setTitle(R.string.google_maps);
            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

NavDrawerActivity.java that handles the menu items

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        if (id == R.id.nav_first_layout) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new FirstFragment()).commit();
            setTitle(R.string.speed_graph);
            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_second_layout) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new SecondFragment()).commit();
            setTitle(R.string.drive_player);
            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_third_layout) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new ThirdFragment()).commit();
            setTitle(R.string.google_maps);
            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Go Check Out All Driving Data in the Play Store!");
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

ThirdFragment.java (That handles the map)

```
public class ThirdFragment extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback
{
    View myView;
    private GoogleMap mMap;


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.third_layout, container, false);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.third_layout);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        return myView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney, Australia, and move the camera.
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

third_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What do you mean `it doesn't lik it`? did you encountered any error? here's a tutorial video how to implement Google Maps Fragment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7CjBlxQRf7s

Comment: This is actually solved now. But thank you :)

Comment: Yea! But if you have any ideas on my other questions I have out there, that would be greatly appreciated as well!

Comment: Hi James, may I know your additional question?

Comment: Hi @d.datul1990, it was just a generalized statement. I have a lot of Android questions that have gone unanswered, the one I need the most answered on is this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39761656/google-maps-route-from-json-results

Comment: Let mi check the SO ticket, will update you soon.